# Auto close modal after palying video. Timeout function not working

Tags: javascript, function, bootstrap-modal

I do not know coding at all and have pieced together this much only via the internet.

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ne2Lp7s/)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#overlay').modal('show');

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlay').modal('hide');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: you can wrap your video with `<video>` tag then you can use video `ended` event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this

```
setTimeout(() => {
  $('#overlay').hide();
}, 12000);
```

.modal class is part of a different library/framework (I suspect Bootstrap)

Also, you do not need `$('#overlay').modal('show')` if you want it to appear on page load

AND, if you want it to happen on video end, then:

1) You need to remove attribute `loop` from your `<video>` element

2) You need to add an EventListener that will wait for an event of video ending.

Something like

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.onended = (event) => {
  $('#overlay').hide();
};
```

JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/67ujLnsx/